# Data binding in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, object, backbone.js

I am trying to implement a simple notification system for a personal project, but I got stuck in how to bind events to the notifications in order to response to user actions, like accept or deny.

So far what i got is an object which is created dynamically.

```
/* reference to notifications */
var notifications = [];

// the notification object
var Notification = function(travelInfo){
    this.el = $('#notifications_container');
    this.id = Math.random().toString().substring(7);
    this.travelInfo = travelInfo;
    this.read = false;

};


Notification.prototype.init = function(){
    this.addOne();
    this.render();
    this.bindFunctions();
}

/* dynamically created */
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        var notification = new Notification(travelInfo);
        notifications.push(notification);
        notification.init();
    }
```

This object is supposed to render and actually bind events to the rendered element in order to keep track of the actions of every notification independently:

```
// render the view of a notification
Notification.prototype.render = function(){
    var source = $('#notification-template').html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
    var data = this.travelInfo;
    result = template(data);
    $('#notifications_container').append(result);
}

Notification.prototype.addOne = function(){
    var number = +$('#notifications_indicator').html();
    $('#notifications_indicator').html(number += 1);
}

Notification.prototype.removeOne = function(){
    var number = +$('#notifications_indicator').html();
    $('#notifications_indicator').html(number -= 1);
}

Notification.prototype.alertId= function(){
    alert('the notification with id:' + this.id + ' is accepted');
}

Notification.prototype.bindFunctions = function(){
    var self = this;
    this.el.on('click', 'li .accept', function(){
        self.alertId();
    });
}
```

The problem with my approach is that actually if I create 10 elements the click event is triggered 10 times showing 10 alerts. What I want to know is how can I implement a system in which I render an element and also bind events to that element something like backbone's way to bind events to every view item. I feel backbone is so big for what I need right now that is just the notification system. I hope you guys could help me to find a way to do this.

Comment: You're binding to the click event 10 times, can you not bind to the actual element being clicked?  If not can you just see if you've bound to the container once and then not bind again?

Comment: which events you are trying to bind to object.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer what i want is for example bind a event to when you click the accept button in the notification to set the read state of the object from false to true.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat well actually what i want is too keep the relation of the DOM element rendered to the object created, but dont know how to achieve it

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading your question correctly, you are over-thinking this one a little bit.

I believe that you are looking for something like this:

```
<div>
<!-- This is where your HTML is -->
<button type="button" data-post-id="10">Delete this post</button>
<button type="button" data-post-id="11">Delete this post</button>
</div>
```

Now, on your onclick handler:

```
function handleDeleteClick() {
  // `this` should be a reference to the element.
  postId = this.getAttribute("data-post-id");
  // Do something with postId
}
```

To complete out the code...

```
element.setAttribute("data-post-id", "11");
element.removeAttribute("data-post-id");
```

Comment: well actually i was thinking in that way because every object brings a certain data like username and other info so i wanted the data of this elemens binded to the objects , but following your suggestion y could do something like store every notification in the notifications array ant then render the div notification like `data-id="0"` and then in the click handler take that id as a reference of the notification clicked and do the action, do you think is a good aproach?